# Exposing Dagger Components defined in an Android Library

Tags: android, dagger-2, aar

How does an Android application in one gradle module include dagger @Modules defined in an other Android Library (.aar)?

I'm trying to have a generic library that provides a set of functionality defined thru dagger @Module's able to have have them injected into Applications that depend on that library

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        LibraryAppModule.class
})
public interface LibraryComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        LibraryComponent build();
    }

    void inject(LibraryApplication app);

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);
}
```

```
@Module
public class LibraryAppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    ServiceFoo provideServiceFoo(Context context) {
        return new ServiceFoo(context);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    ServiceBar provideServiceBar(Context context, ServiceFoo serviceFoo) {
        return new ServiceBar(context, serviceFoo);
    }

}
```

Now in the Application that has a dependency for this library (build.gradle) I've tried the following:

```
implementation project(":Library")
```

Application using the library

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        LibraryAppModule.class
})
public interface ExampleApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        ExampleApplicationComponent build();
    }

    void inject(ExampleApplication app);

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);
}
```

[image: The project layout - library and app depending on library]
This is an example of the place where I'm getting the issue (a null object). This is in a separate module that depends on the library.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    ServiceFoo serviceFoo;

    @Inject
    ServiceBar serviceBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serviceFoo.downloadImages();

        serviceBar.uploadImages();
    }
}
```

I expect to see the LibraryAppModule's services to be available in my Activities using @Inject. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I've created a sample project to highlight the issue: https://github.com/PeregrineFalcon/DaggerExampleLibrary

If you put a break point at the MainActivity.java:25, you'll see both serviceFoo and serviceBar are null and not injected/instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue 2 things needed to be done.

1. The `MainActivity` had to extend `DaggerAppCompatActivity` (this ensures during `onCreate()` for our Activity that `inject()` is called, but for this to work there needs to be an `AndroidInjector` for the Activity.
2. This is accomplished by using `@ContributesAndroidInjector` within a module that I defined and installed into the `ExampleApplicationComponent`

```
@Module
public abstract class ExampleApplicationActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();
}
```

Now within the `MainActivity`, the Services I want injected from the library module are non-null.

Here's is a git commit that shows the difference implementing this fix.
https://github.com/PeregrineFalcon/DaggerExampleLibrary/commit/1ebfdecfa3684c7ac124b9f6a4cecd23712a74fd

Hope this helps someone else who trying to do a multi-module Dagger Android project with `@Modules` provided through the library.

Comment: The answer I gave below will also work, but will require you to create an additional builder in the Activity. Your approach of using AndroidInjector is better as it avoids code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

A class that wants a property injected into it should call `inject()`!

Since you want `serviceFoo` injected in `MainActivity`, you should call `inject()` from `onCreate()`. However, where is `inject()` defined for you to just call it? Hence, you additionally declare `inject()` in `ExampleApplicationComponent`.

All that said, it looks like your understanding of dagger is incomplete. Recommend [this](https://aknay.github.io/2017/09/29/di-injection-with-dagger2-hello-world-example-for-android.html) blog post.

Comment: I'll give that post a read. Thanks. With that said the inject call is part of the fact I'm extending DaggerApplication, but I did notice that my MainActivity is not extending DaggerCompatActivity will fix and see if that helps.